# Is it possible to change a graphs x and y axis major/minor units using openpyxl?

Tags: openpyxl

I have tried the following but none work.

```
chart.auto_axis = False

chart.x_axis.unit = 365

chart.set_y_axis({'minor_unit': 100, 'major_unit':365})
```

changing the max and min scale for both axis is straight forward

```
chart.x_axis.scaling.min = 0

chart.x_axis.scaling.max = 2190

chart.y_axis.scaling.min = 0

chart.y_axis.scaling.max = 2
```

so I'm hoping there is a straight forward solution to this. Here is a mcve.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
import datetime
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
['data point 1', 'data point2'],
[25, 1],
[100, 2],
[500, 3],
[800, 4],
[1200, 5],
[2100, 6],]

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)

chart = ScatterChart()
chart.title = "Example Chart"
chart.style = 18
chart.y_axis.title = 'y'
chart.x_axis.title = 'x'
chart.x_axis.scaling.min = 0
chart.y_axis.scaling.min = 0
chart.X_axis.scaling.max = 2190
chart.y_axis.scaling.max = 6

xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
yvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_row=7)
series = Series(values=yvalues, xvalues=xvalues, title="DP 1")
chart.series.append(series)

ws.add_chart(chart, "D2")

wb.save("chart.xlsx")
```

I need to automate changing the axis to units of 365 or what ever.

Comment: Welcome, please provide us with mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Yilun I have added a mcve. thanks.

Comment: Are you looking at changing the x axis ticks to 0, 365, 730 etc.?

Comment: Hi Yilun, yes I need to change the x axis ticks to a number determined by the programme e.g 365 if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very late answer, but I figured out how to do this just after finding this question.

You need to set the major unit axis to 365.25, and the format to show just the year:

```
chart.x_axis.number_format = 'yyyy'
chart.x_axis.majorUnit = 365.25
```

Comment: Thanks Steve and apologies for not responding sooner. still quite new to stackoverflow and getting used to everything.